# How to simplify some code using defmacro

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp

I wrote two functions like this, but as you see most part of them are identical, so I want to write a macro to simplify them.

I understand the simple macro examples in my textbook, but I don't know how to write my own.

Here's my code:

```
 (defn load-dict
       ;  "Load database from a txt file previous saved"
       [fname]
       (with-open [rdr (io/reader fname)]
                  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
                         (println line)
                         (def vvv (clojure.string/split line #"\s"))
                         ;(println (str "count of vvv is " (count vvv)))
                         (if (< 1 (count vvv))
                           (add- dict (gen-word (nth vvv 0) (nth vvv 2) (nth vvv 1))))
                         )))
 (defn load-article
       ;  "Load article from a txt file"
       [fname]
       (with-open [rdr (io/reader fname)]
                  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
                         (println line)
                         (def vvv (clojure.string/split line #"\s"))
                         ;(println (str "count of vvv is " (count vvv)))
                         (if (< 1 (count vvv))
                           (add- article vvv ))
                         )))
```

Should I write a macro like:

```
(defmacro load- [target fname &expr)
  `(... 
    (add- ~target expr)))
```

I actually don't know how to write such a macro.  I just hate duplicate code.

PS, the tow function work fine. I don't care about the variable this is part of the code.

Comment: Use macros to get rid of boilerplate stuff, use functions to get rid of duplicate code

Answer (score 5):

I would use a let block instead of def. Using def will bind a var and define vvv in your namespace. A macro is not really needed. You could simplify your code like this:

```
(defn load-from
   "Load database from a txt file previous saved"
   [fname load-fn]
   (with-open [rdr (io/reader fname)]
              (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
                     (println line)
                     (let [vvv (clojure.string/split line #"\s")]
                       (when (< 1 (count vvv))
                         (load-fn vvv))))))
```

And invoke it like this

```
(load-from "myfile.txt" #(add- dict (apply gen-word (take 3 %))))
(load-from "myfile.txt" #(add- article %))
```

Comment: Your code sames concise, except the (take 3 %) clause just take first 3 member of %, the sequence is not right here. so I modify the function gen-word to fix that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that the order in your (nth vvv 0), (nth vvv 2)... was not sequential. If gen-word is now happy to take the first three of vvv in order, I leave the code like it is. Or I can change it if you have any wishes.

Answer (score 3):

user1944838 is correct here in that you don't need a macro, and since macros make code ,which does not need them, slightly harder to work with in some contexts (you can't pass it to `map` or `apply` for instance), using functions is preferable in practice. Understanding how to write macros correctly is however very important.

I would write this as a template macro that binds a name you pass it to each word and then call the body you pass to the macro which would in turn use that word through the symbol name.

```
(defmacro with-loaded-article                                                                                                                                             
  [[name-for-line fname] & body]                                                                                                                                          
  `(with-open [rdr# (io/reader ~fname)]                                                                                                                                   
     (doseq [line# (line-seq rdr#)]                                                                                                                                       
       (println line#)                                                                                                                                                    
       (let [~name-for-line (clojure.string/split line# #"\s")]                                                                                                           
         ~@body))))
```

- The `[name-for-line fname]` expression destructures the first argument into a single "binding form" that will be used to generate a symbol and the values that it will resolve to. This format is very common in "with-*" macros such as `with-open` except here I only take one binding form to keep the code smaller.
- the `rdr#` and `line#` symbols inside the syntax-quote are a feature of syntax quote called "auto gensyms" that causes any symbol in side the syntax quote ending with # to be replaced by a unique, though consistent symbol in the resulting expression.
- the `~@` is the splicing-unquote feature of syntax-quotes that causes `body` in this case to be inserted without adding `( )` around it.

We can see how this expands with `macroexpand-1` and `pprint` hint: `(use 'clojure.pprint)`

```
hello.core> (pprint (macroexpand-1 
                      `(with-loaded-article [line "tmp.txt"] (println line))))                                                                                 
(clojure.core/with-open                                                                                                                                                   
 [rdr__6337__auto__ (clojure.java.io/reader "tmp.txt")]                                                                                                                   
 (clojure.core/doseq                                                                                                                                                      
  [line__6338__auto__ (clojure.core/line-seq rdr__6337__auto__)]                                                                                                          
  (clojure.core/println line__6338__auto__)                                                                                                                               
  (clojure.core/let                                                                                                                                                       
   [hello.core/line (clojure.string/split line__6338__auto__ #"\s")]                                                                                                      
   (clojure.core/println hello.core/line))))
```

And when we run the resulting code we get the lines of the file as sequences:

```
hello.core> (with-loaded-article [line "tmp.txt"] (println line))                                                                                                         
hello world                                                                                                                                                               
[hello world]                                                                                                                                                             
world hello                                                                                                                                                               
[world hello]                                                                                                                                                             
and internet hello as well                                                                                                                                                
[and internet hello as well]
```